# SwiftUI Image not shown in xcode preview canvas

Tags: swiftui, xcode11.4

I have added custom target as a framework to use in my codebase. I can't see image **in preview canvas**. When I run in **simulator, image is there.**

[image]
[image]

```
VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        Text("Hello World")
        Image("icon_star")
        .resizable()
        .renderingMode(.original)
        .frame(width: 14, height: 14)

    }.background(Color.white)
```

Any suggestion

Thanks

Comment: What file type is the image? I ran this in xcode 11.5 with a sample png file and it worked.

Comment: I tried png, pdf. I created a custom framework and added to project. then started failing.

Comment: Possibly try updating Xcode to the newest version because maybe that’s the problem? Updating fixed a different bug for me.